# How to run WSL programs within AutoIt?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, autoit

I'm trying to run a linux console application using AutoIt.
So far I was successful in generating a batch file with the following command:

```
wsl /home/ggeorgiev/DD/myprogram --json_file /mnt/c/Users/ggeorgiev/my_input.json
```

This batch runs successfully from cmd, powershell and also when I just double click on it in the explorer. So, I'm thinking that part is okay.

In AutoIt, I'm trying to run the same batch file ("JBDD_start.bat") using the following function:

```
Func RunJBDD()
    
    Local $iPID = Run("cmd.exe " &  "JBDD_start.bat", @WorkingDir, @SW_HIDE, BitOR($STDERR_CHILD, $STDOUT_CHILD,$RUN_CREATE_NEW_CONSOLE ))
    Local $sOutput = ""
    While 1
        $sOutput &= StdoutRead($iPID)
        If @error Then ; Exit the loop if the process closes or StdoutRead returns an error.
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Stdout Read:", $sOutput)
    WEnd

    $sOutput = ''
    While 1
        $sOutput &= StderrRead($iPID)
        If @error Then ; Exit the loop if the process closes or StderrRead returns an error.
            ExitLoop
        EndIf
        MsgBox($MB_SYSTEMMODAL, "Stderr Read:", $sOutput)
    WEnd
EndFunc
```

It doesn't show anything in the StdErr nor in StdOut message boxes.
Any suggestions on what may have gone wrong or how to find what happens "behind the scenes" are highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, maybe it helps to get your output.

```
ConsoleWrite( _getDOSOutput('ping 4.2.2.2') & @CRLF)

Func _getDOSOutput($command)
    Local $text = '', $Pid = Run('"' & @ComSpec & '" /c ' & $command, '', @SW_HIDE, 2 + 4)
    While 1
        $text &= StdoutRead($Pid, False, False)
        If @error Then ExitLoop
        Sleep(10)
    WEnd
    Return $text
EndFunc   ;==>_getDOSOutput
```

Comment: Thanks Xenobiologist, I tried your approach with my command but didn't get any console output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with AutoIt, but I'm going to take an educated guess here.  If I'm wrong, at least it might help someone else.

I notice that AutoIt comes with both 32-bit and 64-bit executables.  Make sure you are either:

- Using the 64-bit version to execute your batch file
- Or, if you really do need to run the 32-bit version of AutoIt, call `C:\Windows\Sysnative\wsl.exe`

Comment: I'm not sure why the bit -ness of AutoIt executable would make any difference. I tried both with no luck.